# Why are photos in iCloud storage as well as iCloud backups for each device?

Tags: iphone, backup, photos

My partner and I both have an iPhone and iPad.

My photos are in iCloud and iCloud backup is enabled for both devices.  Photos are not included in the backups as expected.

My partners photos are in iCloud and as distinct to the configuration on my device backups, hers includes and item for backing up the photo library.  When this is turn on for each device the backup grows very large due to including the photos and prevents the backup from being taken.  When this is disabled iCloud tells us that photo storage has been disabled and will be deleted in 30 days.

I’ve deleted both device backups and created them from scratch with the backup photo library option turned off.  Both devices show that photos are in iCloud, yet when I connect to iCloud from my PC it continues to count down the days to when photos will be deleted from iCloud storage.

How do we keep photo storage enabled in iCloud and avoid having photos included in each device backup?

Comment: A relevant thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280464/are-photos-still-backed-up-in-icloud-backup-even-if-icloud-photo-library-is-off